# Pass Data from android in home to android in office via online

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino, android-bluetooth

I have a problem, I build an application for android that can open a single led with the use of bluetooth module and it succesfully works, now my problem is what if I want to open my led in my home while im at my office. What will I do is I will left another android that can open the led in my office and I will make another android application that will pass a data in my database and that data will retrieve by my android in my office and will trigger to open the LED.. I need tips on how I will gonna do that.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is have a realtime database like [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) to store your data you need to communicate. So when a data is changed or updated your Phones will have the fresh data in sync. and then you can trigger changes accordingly
 
For eg, if the device in your office, clicks (Turn On LED), it will update the Firebase database with a value like (true), on the other side the device at your home would read the value, and check if the value is (true), then run the code to turn on the LED

Comment: firebase realtime database is good but why it only change the text when i open the screen.. its not changing if the screen is off